# What is the most efficient way to define many global variables in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, global-variables

I want to define many global variables in MATLAB and I want the function to run as fast as possible.
Before I started work on this project, the previous coder basically used this:

```
global var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9;
global var10 var11 var12 var13 var14 var15 var16;
global var17 var18;
```

He kept defining variables until he reached the default 75 column marker.
I have done tic toc testing and found a savings of about 2 nanoseconds per execution if I use "..."

```
global var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 ...
       var10 var11 var12 var13 var14 var15 var16 ...
       var17 var18;
```

The savings may be pointless and may not represent the best way to declare this many variables.

These global variables will be modified within the code and other functions. They are never cleared. They are simply re-declared each time teh function runs and within other functions.

Perhaps it would be more efficient to run it all in one line; without "..."?

Comment: how long will it take you change all the current definitions to `...`? how many times are you going to run this code? is it worth 2 nsec savings? the rest of the code is fully optimized? wouldn't it be better to eliminate `global` altogether?

Comment: In that case I'd use scripts, not functions. Calling a script from another lets you share all variables among those scripts

Comment: If the code is to be used extensively and it's really worth spending time rewriting parts of it, I would spend more time getting rid of all the `global` variable (_Sorry ... I'm allergic to them_)

Comment: @Shai 
how long will it take you change all the current definitions to ...? 
About 5 minutes; It's only 7 functions and used like this each time.

how many times are you going to run this code? 
10 times per second for about 20 minutes.

is it worth 2 nsec savings? 
It adds up...

the rest of the code is fully optimized? 
Heavens no... I should look there first, but I am interested in this optimization.

wouldn't it be better to eliminate global altogether?
Yes. But I want a backup strategy if I can't do this.

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll look into this, but everything works as is as functions...

Comment: @Hoki I agree. The original author passes global variables into functions as well... Then declares them again. I was wondering about this optimization for the global variables I can't eliminate.

Comment: If you're declaring this many variables as global, you're doing something *wrong*. At the very least, and if they're all related, you could pack them in a structure; then you would only have to declare that structure as global.

Comment: @Hoki global variables are not evil. There can definitely be reasons where you want to use them. Also, the globals in matlab have been implemented in a way that makes it almost impossible to overwrite them by mistake. Still, I agree that globals should be avoided if possible and in this case it seems that the design initially is not thought through. However, such coce may be terrible to work with so I understand if OP is a bit afraid to touch it. To Steven Bumbler, I would recommend you to place the globals in a struct to easier keep track of everything here.

Comment: Your estimate of a 2ns time saving is not reliable - `tic` and `toc` are not able to reliably estimate such short durations. Even if accurate, 2ns is an absurdly small duration to care about - especially when the very use of globals will slow down your application vastly more than the style in which you declare them.

Comment: @patrik, indeed they can be useful, but at least should be restricted to a very minimum number. So many `global`s is a sure source of confusion if someone else have to reuse the code later on. Gathering them in a `struct` is definitely good advice. My biggest problem with `global` is that they blur the notion of scope. They should only be used when the scope is well understood, but in practice, novice users (with unclear scope) use them a lot, and experienced user who understand enough what they're doing tend to avoid them ... should be the opposite. that's why they're often a red flag for me.

Comment: @StevenBumbler. "_The original author passes global variables into functions as well... Then declares them again._" That is even more of a red flag. Be aware that in a function which receive the global as parameter, if the value is changed _before_ the global declaration, then when it is declared as global, the value will be automatically reverted to what it was in the global workspace before the function modified it (although you should get a warning or at list an mlint flag in cases like this).

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. I spoke to my colleague who worked on one of the functions. No one knew how to keep track of the value of variables after they went into a function. A cheap way to fix this is to declare it as a global variable, so you can always see it in the Workspace. Then what happened is they left those in the algorithm and lost track of which ones should actually be global, thus a snowball effect. Based on everyone's comments, I should avoid the use of global variables. However, if I must use them, create a struct that organizes related variables and just declare that.

Comment: Right now, I'll work on eliminating as many global variables as possible.